# Should .htaccess be versioned in source control?

Tags: apache, version-control

If you follow the principle that an application should run "out of the box" when pulled out of version control, `.htaccess` should be included. Something doesn't feel right about that though, as it doesn't really feel *part* of the application. I'm conflicted, could someone put my mind at rest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I typically do keep an application's .htaccess in source control which includes the Apache configuration required for the application to run, that is, rewrite rules which are not specific to the server it is running on, access to environment variables, etc.

Think about it this way - if the .htaccess file contains rewrite rules used by your application, those are effectively functioning as part of the application routing and therefore *are* part of the application.

If you are packaging an application for others to download and use, you should probably include a skeletal .htaccess file which includes the rules needed to make the application run. If your application is only intended to run on your own server and you keep all its relevant Apache config in .htaccess other than VirtualHost configuration, I would say it does indeed belong in source control.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem for us, too, and I know what you mean about 'not feeling right'.

However, for me the issue is not about being feeling that .htaccess is not *part of the application*, as bits of it clearly are.  The issue is more that that the file mixes application-specific code (routing, etc.) with installation-specific stuff (local URL rewrites, authentication/access rules, etc.).  Ideally you would version control the application-specific rules but not the installation-specific rules, but of course this is not possible as both need to be in the same file.

I can think of four approaches to managing this.  The optimal one will depend on your particular situation (and may vary from project-to-project):

1. Michael's second suggestion is the best option, if you control the deployments.  Namely, keep application-specific code in the .htaccess file, under version control, and any installation-specific code in your main Apache VirtualHost directive.  This gives full separation but is not a viable solution if you don't have direct access to the main Apache config or are distributing to third-parties.  It also may be problematic if you have multiple applications installed under the same site root, if some of those installation-specific elements vary between applications.
2. Version control the application-specific elements of your .htaccess file, with clear comment markers, e.g. `### FOO APPLICATION SETTINGS - DO NOT CHANGE ###` and `### ADD ANY ADDITIONAL LOCAL CONFIG BELOW THIS LINE ####` and do not version anything that is installation-specific.  This is fine if the rules are simple enough to not really cause conflicts, but is not great if your skeletal file requires users to modify existing lines (e.g. `RewriteBase`), as you will likely end up with merge conflicts down the line.  It also runs the risk of unwanted edits getting into your repository if deployments are version-controlled (as is probably the case for dev versions, at least) and it runs the risks of local changes being blown away by an upgrade if not (e.g. public zipfile distributions).
3. What we settled on as a good alternative is to version control a file called `.htaccess.sample` which can contain both application-specific rules and (where relevant) suggestions for installation-specific rules that users may find useful.  This is easy to maintain and deploy whether or not version control is being used, but makes upgrades slightly harder as users will need to hand-merge any changes into their local `.htaccess` file.  In our case, upgrades are always done by developers therefore this is not a big issue, assuming appropriate diff tools are available.
4. Same as #2, except you also provide a script to automatically apply any modifications.  More work to set up, not necessarily more work to maintain, depending how you implement it (e.g. if it just replaces a block of code between some markers) and possibly worthwhile if you are distributing to a wide user base.  This is what Wordpress does, for example.